# Make Hibernate Drop Table Cascade

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` setting but I also create a view based on one of the tables in SQL after hibernate generates the database using `hibernate.import_files=db/create.sql`.

The next time it runs hibernate cannot drop the existing table because the view depends on it.

How do I make hibernate drop table cascade so that the view gets dropped as well?

Defining the entity like this doesn't seem to have an effect

```
@Entity
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue - a view definition (with corresponding JPA mapping) that blocked other table to be dropped.

The solution that works for me was to use *javax.persistence.** properties that gives you more control over create/drop scripts. So instead of using plain `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` I've used `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`. That way I was able to first drop the view and then referenced table.

By using `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script-then-metadata"/>` you can combine user-defined script with schema auto-creation.

You can read more about these properties here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm