# Hibernate H2 specify drop table order

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, h2

I have pretty much the same problem like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59364212/7840514). Hibernate can't drop the tables of my in-memory test database after each SpringBootTest (e.g. when running mvn test). The desired behavior would be `ddl-auto=create-drop`, but this doesn't work.

I think the reason could be an invalid order of the `DROP TABLE` statements, so that Hibernate tries to delete tables on which other tables still depend on.

My data.sql script only contains `INSERT` statements and the schema is automatically created based on my entities. I tried adding `DROP TABLE` statements to the top of data.sql and they all pass (`ddl-auto=create`), because I can specify the order in which they have to be dropped.
On the other side, I now have to specify the schema creation in data.sql too..

Is there a way to specify the order of drop statements while not having to specify the schema creation? Or does anyone know a solution for the [initial problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59364212/7840514)?

**EDIT:**

I want to give an example. I have an `User` entity that has relationships to other entities (M:N, 1:N, 1:1). When the schema is created, hibernate drops all tables, creates them and adds constrains:

```
// first test file:
Hibernate: drop table user if exists
... // drop other tables
Hibernate: create table user (username varchar(255) not null, ... , primary key (username))
... // create other tables
Hibernate: alter table X add constraint FKgi38hy0tsrdm332gdjrc0uhm3 foreign key (username) references user
Hibernate: alter table Y add constraint FK5svpy1b71l4jxni0xylrbbdtv foreign key (username) references user
Hibernate: alter table Z add constraint FK5a8fxbb0ug3eo1lisdrrxbbj foreign key (username) references user

// next test file:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot drop "USER" because "FKGI38HY0TSRDM332GDJRC0UHM3, FK5SVPY1B71L4JXNI0XYLRBBDTV, FK5A8FXBB0UG3EO1LISDRRXBBJ" depends on it; SQL statement:
drop table user if exists [90107-200]
```

This process doesn't work after the first test file, because it violates the constrains. This is why I wanted to specify the drop order.

I don't use CascadeType on my entities, could that cause the problem?

Comment: Can you show your mapping and the drop statements?

Comment: Do you really want the code of all my entities?

Comment: First post the drop statements and tell us on which drop it fails. Then we will see if there is an issue with the mapping

Comment: The drop statements don't fail if I specify them manually. It fails if my data.sql only contains the insert statements. But Hibernate should drop the tables after each test, because I use create-drop. This doesn't work tho (error in linked question)

Comment: Oracle address this problem with the [CASCADE CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF54847)
 clause of the  `DROP TABLE` statement. 
H2 has also `CASCADE `[option](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/h2_database/h2_database_drop.htm) but apparently relevant only for views. Having said this it will not help you, as you can manage the `DROP` manually. Anyway a *small reproducible example* (two entities must be sufficient) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Spring Boot does not execute create-drop after each test method. Only after ich Test class.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli well it does not seems so. Not with replace=none option and springboot 2.2.2. It was like that with 2.0.4, but with this option and springboot 2.2.2 db is initilized just once, not dropped, and initialization for next test file fails.

Comment: @MartinMucha Oh yes you are right.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I want it to be dropped after each test file, sorry if I didn't state that.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber thanks for your reply. It's difficult for me to extract an example from the project. But as you mentioned the cascade option: Could the reason be a lack of `CascadeType` specifications at my entity relationships?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I added a sample from the hibernate debug log, does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a work around for my problem. 
As I said, the errors where caused by trying to drop tables on which other tables still depend on. I thought that this could be related to missing `CascadeType` specifcations, but I couldn't fix it.

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782963/7840514) and it works for me. Additional to my `data.sql` file (where all my data is inserted to the auto-created schema) I now have a `drop-tables.sql` where I can specify the correct order of `DROP` statements. This file is executed before the automatic schema creation and therefore solves my problem.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=drop-and-create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source=script-then-metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source=drop-tables.sql
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012915/607637 that works for me. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You must annotate your test classes with DirtiesContext:

```
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = MethodMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
```

This will rebuild the test context and therefore also create-drop your schema.

Read more about this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext

Comment: I think you mean `ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS` but this doesn't solve my problem. Yes it triggers the dropping of the DB schema, but again this throws the described error of the linked question

Comment: in spring-boot 2.2.2 with replace=none this won't help either. I don't know what was changed between 2.0.4 and 2.2.2, I'd like to control that, but I have no idea how to do that, and cannot find answer anywhere. If you know how to force wpring to reinit db after every test file (in my case @DataJpaTest) even if replace=none is in place, please help. I'm not grown onto replace=none, but another thing I'm unable to do is to force autoconfigured datasource to create schema :(