# JPA, Hibernate table configuration error in Spring Project

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am working on a java project that uses Gradle, Spring, Spring Security, JPA and an H2 database. I am trying to use JPA persistence to implement database tables for role, user and usecase-table.

This is my applications.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

Here is my @Entity User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    public User() {
    }
    public User(Long id, String email, String password, String fullname, boolean enabled){
        this.id = id;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.fullname=fullname;
        this.enabled=enabled;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String fullname;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

Here is my @Entity Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
```

Here is one of my repositories for User, the others are pretty much the same:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(final String email);

}
```

Here is MyCapecApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCapecApp {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCapecApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCapecApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(RoleRepository roleRepository) {

        return args -> {


            Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
            if (adminRole == null) {
                Role newAdminRole = new Role();
                newAdminRole.setRole("ADMIN");
                roleRepository.save(newAdminRole);
            }

            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("USER");
            if (userRole == null) {
                Role newUserRole = new Role();
                newUserRole.setRole("USER");
                roleRepository.save(newUserRole);
            }
            log.info("Roles found with findll():");
            log.info("----------------------------------");
            for(Role rol : roleRepository.findAll()){
                log.info((roleRepository.toString()));
            }
            log.info("");
        };

    }
```

And these are the errors I am getting.

```
2020-04-21 16:34:21.668  WARN 16560 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table role if exists" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table role if exists" via JDBC Statement
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot drop "ROLE" because "FKT4V0RRWEYK393BDGT107VDX0X" depends on it; SQL statement:
drop table role if exists [90107-200]
```

And this is the next error.

```
2020-04-21 16:34:21.678  WARN 16560 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), enabled boolean not null, fullname varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), enabled boolean not null, fullname varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USER" already exists; SQL statement:
    create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), enabled boolean not null, fullname varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42101-200]
```

The errors are the same for all three tables. I connected my database 'testdb' in the database window in intellij. Previously, i had created the three tables in the database window for user, role and usecase-table, of the same name, but i still got errors, and i was under the impression that JPA did that for you when you run the program. If that is the problem then perhaps i just made the table wrong? If so can someone please tell me the right way to do it? When i boot the project on localhost everything runs, but user input is not being stored in the database tables.

This is the first time i have ever done any project using spring or databases or of such complexity, so i apologize for my ignorance in advance. I am a student, and I really want to learn this. Please let me know if there is anything else i should include. Thanks again and I really appreciate any help you guys can offer me, and I am very grateful for your patience and your time.

Comment: There is already an answer on that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561551/hibernate-h2-specify-drop-table-order

Comment: that answer does not work

Comment: Have you defined drop-tables.sql script in src/main/resources?

Comment: I have not done that drop-table.sql because i dont know what should go inside it. i dont know how to specify which order to drop the tables in. i added those lines to my applications.properties file but neither of those answers specified what should be in the drop-table.sql file. Can you please explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Create a SQL script and drop the join table `user_roles`, then `user` and `roles` (in that specific order). https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop_table.asp